# Is there any difference between "to pull over" and "to park"?

Tags: meaning, phrasal-verbs

These verbs have pretty much the same meaning.

[To pull over](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/pull-over) - If a vehicle or driver pulls over, it stops by the side of the road.

[To park](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/park_2) - To leave a vehicle into a place where you are going to leave it for a period of time.

For example.

> Let's pull over and have a look at the map.

Can we say

> Let's park and have a look at the map.

with the same meaning?

Comment: You don't "pull over" at your destination, you "park" there.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the senses that you give above, we use *pull over* more often to indicate a *brief* pause while travelling: to look at a map, to let others pass in front, in response to a police car's red light, etc. We can also pull over without stopping, while to park implies stopping.

We use *park* more often to indicate a longer stop at a destination.

We can say *Let's park and have a look at the map* with the basic meaning of stopping clear, but it would be more common to use *pull over* in that utterance.

Comment: Good explanation!

Comment: *Parking* also tends to imply the intent to get out of the vehicle.

Comment: @Hellion Or your intention to [stay in the car ](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/park#Verb) (#6), if you catch my drift.

Answer (score 7):

"Pull over" is more of parking away from the road proper in order to do something (like getting snacks, or for police).

> Can we pull over, because I want to eat.
>
> The police pulled him over to test him for drunk driving.

"Park" is used **generally** for leaving one's own vehicle/whatever (stationary) at a place.

> He parked his car in his driveway, and now someone broke the car window.

**"Pull over" is more specific on the manner of how/why the car gets parked, while "park" doesn't have such implications.**

In your case, they pretty much have the same meaning, except with the specific-ness I noted above.

Answer (score 3):

And to specify where you want to stop and look at the map, you ...

> ... pull over **to** the curb.

but

> ... park **at** the curb.

or

> ... park **by** the curb.

(or ... park *on* the curb.)

Answer (score 3):

"Pull over" generally means to stop at the side of the road, in a place where you normally wouldn't park for an extended period of time (i.e., not in a designated parking space).

On the other hand, you "park" in a variety of places: a parking lot, a driveway, a parking space, etc. You don't usually "pull over" into those places.